# Selective operations in a Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a row matrix

```
f[m_] = Table[f[m, n], {n, 1, 6}]
```

I want to use it to define another matrix `g[m_, i_, j_]` such that

```
g[m_, i_, j_] = f[m]
```

with `j`th element is substituted with the summation of `j`th & `i`th elements while `i`th elements turns to be zero.

Comment: I *think* I understood your question, but it's useful to include a sample input with the desired output in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
f[m_] = Table[f[m, n], {n, 1, 6}];
g[m_, i_, j_] := ReplacePart[f[m], {j -> f[m][[j]] + f[m][[i]], i -> 0}]
```

Similarly:

```
g[m_, i_, j_] := Normal@SparseArray[{j -> f[m][[j]] + f[m][[i]], i -> 0, k_ :> f[m][[k]]}, Length@f[m]]
```

Or:

```
g[m_, i_, j_] := SparseArray[{{j, i} -> 1, {i, i} -> 0, {k_, k_} -> 1}, {#, #} &@Length@f[m]].f[m]
```

Then,

```
g[m, 1, 3]
(* {0, f[m, 2], f[m, 1] + f[m, 3], f[m, 4], f[m, 5], f[m, 6]} *)
```